# how to replace contents of current variable?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

**How do I modify my variable to a value that is a function of my variable?**

For example, suppose I define a variable called `myBody`:

[image]

I'd like to be able to replace the contents like so:

[image]

`replace(variables('myBody'),items('For_each'),variables('myGuid'))`

Keep in mind that I'm inside of a **For_Each**, meaning that for every iteration, I need to update this variable.

**How can we replace the contents of a variable?**

Comment: So, I have to ask...have you even tried?  I don't see anything unusual about this.  Are you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you need to use the replace action here, the "Set variable" action should suffice. Just set the Guid which you can fetch from the HTTP body, you could even define the scheme which the HTTP request receives so you don't have to store it in a defined variable/parameter. Then the Guid would be so-called 'Dynamic content'.

[Http request scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Hpk.png)

[Dynamic content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3RnQ.png)